# Convolution, How to develop this piecewise?

Tags: integration, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, convolution, piecewise-continuity

This is an exercise from my book on hilbert spaces. I don't understand the last step. Can someone develop the procedure to get that piecewise?.

Convolution $\left(f\ast g\right)$

Indicator function  $\mathcal{X}_{\left[0,1\right]}$

If $f=g=\mathcal{X}_{\left[0,1\right]}$, you have $\left(f\ast g\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t-u)g(u)du=\int_{0}^{1}\mathcal{X}_{\left[0,1\right]}(t-u)du=length\Big(\left[0,1\right]\cap\left[t-1,t\right]\Big)$

so $t-u\in\left[0,1\right]$ if and only if $u\in\left[t-1,t\right]$. Therefore,

\begin{equation*}
\left(f\ast g\right)= \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{ll} 
  0 \quad &\text{if}\, t\leq 0 \\
  t \quad &\text{if}\, 0\leq t\leq 1 \\
     2-t  \quad &\text{if}\, 1\leq t\leq 2 \\
     0 \quad &\text{if}\, t\geq 2
  \end{array}
 \right.
\end{equation*}

Comment: just verify all the cases. that's it. If $t< 0$  then  $[0,1]\cap [t-1,t]=\emptyset$, so it has $0$ length. Do the same for other $3$ cases.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

By "last step" I suppose you mean "the last equality". There is also a "(t)" missing on the left hand side of the first equality. Also, be sure not to confuse $\chi_{[0,1]}(t-u)$ with the product of two functions.

To avoid such possible misunderstandings, I rewrite all the equations, using the notation $\chi$ for the function $\chi_{[0,1]}$. So

$$ (f*g)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t-u) g(u) du =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi(t-u) \chi(u) du . $$

Now, the first factor in the integrand is $1$ if $$ \begin{align} 0\leq t-u \leq 1 &\iff 0 \geq u-t \geq -1 \iff t-1 \leq u \leq t \\ &\iff u \in [t-1,t] \end{align}$$ and $0$ otherwise. Likewise, the second factor in the integrand is $1$ if $u\in [0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise. Finally, since the integral is the surface under the integrand and the integrand is a (possibly trivial) rectangle of height $1$, the integral can be replaced by the length of the rectangle which is indeed $$length([0,1] \cap [t-1,t]) = \max(\min(1,t) - \max(0, t-1),0).$$

In the last equality, I gave a solution which avoids piecewise analysis. But if you still want to do the piecewise analysis, with the help of @peek-a-boo's comment, everything should be clear.

Comment: It turns out that the $\max$ with respect to $0$ is not necessary in the present example, but I left it in place for the general case which is $$ 
 length ([a,b] \cap [c,d]) = \max( \min[b,d] - \max[a,c],0). $$